# Как сделать чтобы скрипт node.js если внезапно завершает работу перезапускался (CentOS)

Tags: node.js, centos

Как сделать чтобы скрипт node.js если внезапно завершает работу перезапускался

Comment: Зависит от версии centos, если >= 7 , то можно написать systemd unit, если 6, то можно использовать, например, `supervisord`.

Comment: + за supervisord

Comment: + В докере можно сделать. Тут в комплекте ещё и изоляция